# Oxwall - How can I hide logged in member name?

Tags: php, social-networking, oxwall

When use logged in to my oxwall social network site , They getting like Hello `{User name}` - Here actual user name comes who is logged in. So I do not want that to display. I want to keep only Hello there.

So please guide me that how can I remove `{username}` which comes with hello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to ow_system_plugins/base/controllers/ in your Oxwall installation path and open component_panel.php with a code editor :

Find : **$this->setPageHeading(OW::getLanguage()->text('base', 'dashboard_heading'));**

Make above line comment..

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just want to remove it all together with the info provided all I can say is that within your theme folder there is problably a file named header start opening it and searching for "hello" and delete the var after it if it looks right....

However if you just want to display their username rather than their real name... go to admin panel > "User settings" tab > "Display settings" group > change "Real Name"(Default) to "Username" in the dropdown box